# Compiler error for using operator '>>' with ifstream

Tags: c++, visual-c++, io

I am trying to use a custom template for IO, and I getting an **error :**

```
"error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of 
type 'std::ifstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"
```

I have searched and found only suggestions to try including more headers, and have tried including: `string, fstream, iostream, istream, vector`.
 I can use an fstream.get(), but I am trying to get space delimited strings. (The format of my file is lines like this: **`"String1 = String2"`**)

Here is my code:

```
template <typename OutType>
OutType Read(std::ifstream& in)
{
    OutType out;
    in >> out;

    return out;
}
```

Any suggestions are very much appreciated! Thanks!

(P.S. Not sure if it will matter for compiler considerations, but I am using Visual Studio 2013.)

Comment: And what is OutType when you try to call it?

Comment: Probably should read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `OutType` (which you have not shown us) has no `operator>>(istream&, OutType&)`.  You need to define one for every possible `OutType`.

Answer (score 0):

How you are expecting  `OutType` is known to `>>` operator? It understands primitives like `int`,`char`, etc., but if you want to make OutType available to << you should overload the operator.